# what make intent detection/classification different than random text classification?

Tags: classification, text-classification

I'm trying to understand what makes intents detection / classification different than random text classification. I always see examples of intents detection using a json file with the intent as a key and sentences associated to this intent as its values.
while when work on simple text classification the training file is just a csv.
I can't get the difference between the 2 and whats the core difference

Answer (score 1):

It's important to distinguish the **type of problem** versus the **task** itself:

- Text classification is a type of problem where the input (features) is text and the output (target) is a categorical variable (class). The type of problem is part of **how** a problem is solved.
- Intent detection is a specific task, i.e. the job that one wants to perform. A task describes **which** problem is solved.

There are many different tasks which can be treated as text classification problems, for example topic classification, sentiment analysis, author identification, etc.

The input format is not related to any part of the ML design, it's a technical detail.

Answer (score 0):

From various research articles I have read, this is the main purpose/difference between text classification and intent detection/classification

**Text Classification**

It's the activity of labelling natural language texts with relevant categories from a predefined set. Using Natural Language Processing (NLP), text classifiers can automatically analyze text and then assign a set of pre-defined tags or categories based on its content. Some common use cases can be for

- language detection
- sentiment analysis(positive or negative feedback)
- topic detection

**Intent Classification**

Using ML & NLP, an intent classifier automatically analyzes texts and categorizes them into intents.
Its basically used to find the purpose behind the text in hand.
Highly utilized in chatbots